# Prove the multiplication map from the Cartesian product of the set of continuous functions to itself is a continuous map

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

"Let $\mathbb{F}$ be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space.

Define $C(X) = C(X,\mathbb{F})$ as the set of continuous functions $f:X\to \mathbb{F}$ with the norm:

$\lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_\infty = sup\{\lvert f(x)\rvert:x\in X\}$

1. Prove that $\lvert\lvert fg\rvert\rvert_\infty \leq \lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_\infty\lvert\lvert g\rvert\rvert_\infty$ for all $f,g \in C(X)$
2. Prove that the multiplication map $(f,g)\to fg$ is a continuous map from $C(X) \times C(X)$ to $C(X)$"

I can easily prove 1 straight from the definition of our norm, but how do I go about proving 2? Where do I begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|f_ng_n-fg\| \leq \|f_ng_n-f_ng\|+\|f_ng-fg\| \leq \|g_n-g\|\|f_n\|+\|f_n-f\|\|g\| $. Hence $\|f_ng_n-fg\| \leq \|g_n-g\|(\|f\|+\|f_n-f\|)+\|f_n-f\|\|g\| $. I will let you finish the proof.

Comment: Why can we assume that there exists a sequence of functions in C(X) that converges to f? Just because we know f is an element of C(X), so is therefore continuous? Am I right?

Comment: To prove 2) you assume that $f_n \to f$ and  g_n \to $g$ and show that $f_ng_n \to fg$. @Dino